# Hangfire - redis server keys

Tags: c#, redis, console-application, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire.Pro with Redis: 1 single console app with multiple jobs in 1 server, plus 1 Redis instance.

Everytime i start my application Hangfire add a key in Redis to register the process/server.

The format of the key is "[SERVERNAME]:[PID]" (ex: **hangfire:server:localPc:66233:51dc785c-be3d-4a16-9f5s-502f3e699655**).

For each of these keys we got the info of the server in the dashboard and it's a bit confusing having multiple keys but only one real server running.

My questions are:

- Are these keys removed automatically by Hangfire?
- Is there anything native on Hangfire to handle the removal of these keys? like what happen for the executed jobs?

At the moment I've done a workaround and I'm flushing those keys before i start my application(redis-cli) but if there is anything native it would be better.

Many thanks